# Cloud Function being deployed but still callable

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I deployed a Python cloud function to GCP and Cloud Build says the function is successfully deployed. However, in the Cloud Functions console, the function says it is still being deployed and the icon is splinning. When I try call it from my web app, the function runs completely fine despite still "being deployed". After about 30 mins, the function then breaks and the status says there was an error with deployment and the status of the function becomes "Unknown function status". How do I fix this? Here is the cloud function code:

```
def transcribe_audio_from_video_submission(request):
    request_json = request.get_json()

    if not request_json:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Missing JSON in request'}), 400
    
    uid = request_json.get('uid')
    attemptId = request_json.get('attemptId')
    file_path = request_json.get('file_path')

    if not all([uid, attemptId, file_path]):
        return jsonify({'error': 'Missing fields in JSON'}), 400

    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    db = firestore.Client(project=PROJECT_NAME)

    uid = request_json['uid']
    attemptId =  request_json['attemptId']
    file_path = request_json['file_path']

    storage_client = storage.Client(project=PROJECT_NAME)

    bucket_name = BUCKET_NAME

    bucket = storage.Bucket(storage_client, bucket_name, user_project=PROJECTNAME)

    blob = bucket.blob(file_path)

    audio_file_bytes = blob.download_as_bytes()
    # Convert webm to wav
    audio = AudioSegment.from_file(BytesIO(audio_file_bytes), format="webm")
    audio = audio.set_channels(1)
    wav_file = BytesIO()
    audio.export(wav_file, format="wav")
    wav_file.seek(0)  # reset the pointer to the beginning of the file
    wav_file.name = "audio_wav_file.wav"
    transcript = openai.Audio.transcribe("whisper-1", wav_file)
    doc_ref = db.collection('users').document(uid).collection('attempts').document(attemptId)
    doc_ref.update({
        'isAnalysed': True,
        'transcribedText': transcript['text'],
    })

    return f"Transcribed text: {transcript['text']}"
```

Comment: is there any additional info on logs?

Comment: All the logs show a successful deployment has occurred but the status icon is still spinning.

Comment: Even if the status icon is still spinning, the function might still be callable and running correctly. As you mentioned, your web app successfully calls the function despite the ongoing "deploying" status. Monitor the function's behavior and see if it continues to work as expected, and it's possible that the spinning status icon is a result of a caching issue in your browser. Try clearing your browser cache or open an incognito window to see if the status updates correctly. You may also contact [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) to investigate your project thoroughly.